# Commutation rules between itinerant and localized electron operators in s-f Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, commutator, second-quantization

The s-f Model is a model who could describe the  $\textbf{magnetic 4 $\textit{f}$ systems}$, i.e systems where we could identify localized electrons in $4\,\textit{f}$ orbitals and conductions electrons

The interaction between conduction electrons and  $4\,\textit{f}$ electrons,could be described as an intra-atomic exchange interaction between the spins $\hat{{\sigma}}$  of the conduction electrons and the spin $\hat{S}$ of $4\,\textit{f}$ electrons:

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{sf} = -g \sum_{i}\,\hat{\sigma}_{i}\,\cdot\,\hat{S}_{i}
\end{equation}

Here the index $i$ indentify the lattice site in $\textbf{R}_{i}$, $g$ is the exchange coupling constant. For semplicity it is assumed to be identical for all pairs of conduction and $4\,\textit{f}$ electrons

Using the following relations for the spin operators $\hat{\sigma}_{i}$ and $\hat{S}_{i}$

\begin{align}
\hat{S}_{j}^{x} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\hat{S}_{j}^{+} + \hat{S}_{j}^{-}\right) \nonumber \\
\hat{S}_{j}^{y} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\hat{S}_{j}^{+} - \hat{S}_{j}^{-}\right) \nonumber \\
\hat{S}_{j}^{z} &= \hat{S}_{j}^{z} 
\end{align}

and the second quantization rapresentation for the spin operators of conduction electrons

\begin{align}
\hat{ \sigma}_{i}^{+} &=
 \hbar\,\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}\hat{a}_{i,\downarrow} \nonumber \\
 \hat{ \sigma}_{i}^{-} &=
 \hbar\,\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\downarrow}\hat{a}_{i,\uparrow}  \nonumber \\
  \hat{ \sigma}_{i}^{z} &= \frac{\hbar}{2}\,
  \left(
  \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}\hat{a}_{i,\uparrow} 
  -
    \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\downarrow}\hat{a}_{i,\downarrow} 
  \right)
\end{align}

The interaction term $\hat{H}_{sf}$ could be written in the following way

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{sf} 
  =
  -  \frac{1}{2} \, g \, \hbar \sum_{i}
  \left[
  \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}\hat{a}_{i,\downarrow} \hat{S}_{i}^{-} 
+  \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\downarrow}\hat{a}_{i,\uparrow} \hat{S}_{i}^{+} 
    +
\left(
  \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}\hat{a}_{i,\uparrow} 
  -
    \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\downarrow}\hat{a}_{i,\downarrow} 
  \right) \, \hat{S}_{i}^{z}\right]
\end{equation}

Since i have to compute commutators like $\left[\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}, \hat{H}\right]$, where $H$ is the s-f Hamiltonian,i have to know the commutation relations between the annihliation and creation operators of conduction electrons $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma},\,\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}$ and the spin operator of localized electrons  $\hat{S}_{i}^{z}, \hat{S}_{i}^{+}, \hat{S}_{i}^{-}$

I am thinking , since these are two different kind of electrons the commutator between them is 0 , right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. If this is not enough, these operators correspond to different degrees of freedom and you can safely assume that they are commuting.

Comment: Can i formalize it ?

Comment: Yes, but it is trivial. Ladder operators act on occupation numbers that are a different degree of freedom with respect to spin. So, simply $[{\hat a}_{i,\sigma},{\hat S}^\alpha_j]=0$.